Lyx math selection highlighted corners
Lyx math mode has these magenta-colored corners surrounding the selected bit. What are these called? Can I change the appearance of this selection effect, for example, to color the whole interior of the box instead of just the corners?


Those are just part of the interface, not the output. It seems better-suited to connect with the LyX about this (request).
